# Use tktinter input to get string URL and Download Folder

Tags: python, string, selenium, google-chrome, tkinter

I made a script that gets a page with an entire album in mp3 and download each song.
This works like a charm if I insert the data needed in the code, but I wanna to insert it via GUI.
But it wont run. Results the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Luan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\Luan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object
```

Here goes the entire code, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_entry_fields():
    print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (givenurl.get(), givenplace.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, 
         text="Url do Album").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, 
         text="Local para baixar").grid(row=1)

givenurl = tk.Entry(master)
givenplace = tk.Entry(master)

givenurl.grid(row=0, column=1)
givenplace.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(master, 
          text='Quit', 
          command=master.quit).grid(row=3, 
                                    column=0, 
                                    sticky=tk.W, 
                                    pady=4)
tk.Button(master, 
          text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, 
                                                       column=1, 
                                                       sticky=tk.W, 
                                                       pady=4)

tk.mainloop()

# Ferramenta de Robot do Navegador
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# need the below imports to work with Explicit wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

## DEFINE LUGAR ONDE OS ARQUIVOS SERAO SALVOS
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : givenplace}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Windows/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chromeOptions)

browser.get(givenurl)
songs = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('player')

## CODIGO QUE PREVINIRA ERRO NA CONSTATE TROCA DE DOMINIO DO SITE
#site = browser.current_url
#print (site)

## PEGA AS INSFORMACOES DENTRO DO SITE, ARMAZENA DADOS DO ARTISTA E DA MUSICA, FAZ O DOWNLOAD
for i in songs:
    print (i.get_attribute("data-title"))
    print (i.get_attribute("data-mp3url"))
    info = i.get_attribute("data-info")
    down = i.get_attribute("data-mp3url")
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
    browser.get("https://red3mp3.me" +down)
```

Comment: `prefs = {"download.default_directory" : givenplace}` should be `prefs = {"download.default_directory" : givenplace.get()}`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is because the entry is an object, you can't get the data cause you are getting it wrongly. Try to play around with retrieval of the data IN the object, it is most likely a dictionary!

```
givenurl = tk.Entry(master)
givenplace = tk.Entry(master)
```

If you want to use givenurl, **try this**,

```
url_var = givenurl.get()
browser.get(url_var)
```